# Nesting resource routes within /api/ routes

Tags: php, laravel, restful-url, laravel-routing

I was hoping someone could shed some light for me on how to nest my resources within /api/ routes.

For example:

```
Route::resource('sale', 'SaleController');
```

Would be accessed with E.G: `http://something.dev/api/sales`

Any advice on this would be much appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap these in a route group with a `prefix`, like this:

```
Route::group(
    array('prefix' => 'api'),
    function()
    {
        Route::resource('sale', 'SaleController');
    }
);
```

See the docs for more info: http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-prefixing